# fetch value from an array

Tags: php, mysql

I need to fetch value from an array .I need to fetch the value name,value,user_id from an given array

```
$inner_content='[{"name":"radio","value":"1","id":"1","user_id":"admin@gmail.com","web":"571710720","type":"poll_info","pg":"question_response"},{"name":"fav-color[]","value":"blue"}]'


$id='5';  //value given for expample.
$inner="select * from user_response where POLL_ID=$id";
$inner1=mysql_query($inner);
while($ifet=mysql_fetch_assoc($inner1))
{
  $inner_content = $ifet['CONTENT_VALUES'];
  $data1 = json_decode($inner_content);
  $test1[]=array('name'=>$data1->name); 
}
```

Comment: is there associative array..????

Comment: var_dump($data1); what is the output of this?

Comment: the decoded json string turned into object has another dimension inside, its multi leveled, its supposed to be `$data1[0]->name` and so on

Comment: ya multi-level array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In JSON, square brackets denote an array, and curly braces denote an object. As you can see if you look carefully at `$inner_content`, it's an array containing a bunch of objects, so you need to index it.

```
$test1[] = array('name' => $data1[0]->name);
```

This just gets the name from the first object in the array. If you want to get all the names, you could use a `foreach` loop on `$data1` (but only the first one has all the properties that you say you want).

Comment: That's not very meaningful. What is it doing instead? Are you getting any errors or warnings (make sure you have `error_reporting(E_ALL)` enabled)?

Comment: It return the word 'Array'

Comment: @Sougata Presumably the JSON in his actual database isn't like the variable he posted in the question.

Comment: object(stdClass)#2 (7) {
  ["name"]=>
  string(5) "multi"
  ["value"]=>
  string(8) "option 4"
  ["id"]=>
  string(1) "4"
  ["user_id"]=>
  string(15) "admin@gmail.com"
  ["web"]=>
  string(9) "571710720"
  ["type"]=>
  string(9) "poll_info"
  ["pagename"]=>
  string(17) "question_response"
}

Comment: If that's what `var_dump` says, then there's no way that `$data1[0]->name` could return the word `Array`. It should return `multi`.

Comment: I need to display 'multi'.I var dump shows correctlt.but in console shows Array

Comment: Are you doing `echo $test1`? It should be `echo json_encode(test1)`.

Comment: I need tp push that array value into another array as $test[] = array('ID' => $id, 'title' => $datas->title, 'startdate' => $datas->startdate, 'enddate' => $datas->enddate, 'targetusers' => $datas->targetusers, 'maxresponse' => $datas->maxresponse, 'usertype' => $datas->usertype, 'location' => $datas->location, 'status' => $datas->status, 'created_on' => $fet['CREATED_ON'],'response'=>json_encode($test1));

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103256/discussion-between-user3386779-and-barmar).

Comment: You get `Array` when you try to use an array where a string is needed. For instance, if you try to `echo` an array, it will echo `Array`. So somewhere in your code, you're using an array as a string, and that's where this is coming from. It's not coming from what I put in my answer.